# How to animate table view cells when switching between buttons of UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

My application is looking like the below image

[image]
[image]

I have 3 buttons in my segmented control. Assume that hitting the "Department" button will display 3 departments & hitting "Name" button will show 6 names.

I follow the below steps to make this..

1. Create UISegmentedControl by this code

   ```
   segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Department", @"Name", @"ID",nil]];  //Initialize Segmented Control

   segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar; //Define bar type (optional)

   segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; //Define default clicked button

   [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  //Set target and define which method should called when tapping buttons

   self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl; //To add UISegmented Control in the title of the navigation bar
   ```
2. Define the method(`segmentClicked`) for UISegmented Control

   ```
   segment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

   if (segment==0) {
       //Do something for Department tab
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }

   else if (segment==1) {
       //Do something for Name tab
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }

   else {
       //Do something for ID tab
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
   ```
3. Create the cells with reference to the value of segment in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. (So that we can get various cells for each UISegmentedControl buttons)

   ```
   if (segment == 0) {

       cell.textLabel.text = [listOfDepartments objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; //listOfDepartments is the NSMutableArray that contains list of Departments names

   }

   else if (segment == 1) {

       cell.textLabel.text = [listOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];  //listOfNames is the NSMutableArray that contains list of person names

   }

   else {

       cell.textLabel.text = [listOfIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];  //listOfIDs is the NSMutableArray that contains list of person ID's

   }

   return cell;
   ```

So, finally i got the view showed in the above image.

When i press on the UISegmentedControl buttons, the table view reloads its cells & showing corresponding values perfectly. By default, the "Department" button was selected. If i tap the "Name" button(that is, table will show 6 cells instead of 3), The table changes immediately without any animations. It simply hide 3 cells of department names and showing 6 cells that displaying names of persons without any animations. I could not find a way to making the cell changes with smooth animations.

What should i implement to achieve the smooth animations?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` methods which has options for specifying some build-in cool animations.

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewRowAnimationFade,
    UITableViewRowAnimationRight,    
    UITableViewRowAnimationLeft,
    UITableViewRowAnimationTop,
    UITableViewRowAnimationBottom,
    UITableViewRowAnimationNone,        
    UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle,      
} UITableViewRowAnimation;
```

Comment: 'deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:' method asks (NSArray *) indexPaths. I can not understand this...

Answer (score 0):

Use the method reloadSections: withRowAnimation:

If you are having only one section then pass [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] as a first argument in above method. In the second argument you can choose the animation type.

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It may help to try:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

in your `segmentClicked` method, instead of `[self.tableView reloadData];`

These methods sometimes animate table changes better.

Comment: Adding [self.tableView beginUpdates]; & [self.tableView endUpdates]; alone is enough to make animation?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it will work in your situation, but I have used those lines to animate changes to my rows, such as increasing the height to fit more text.  Where table reload looked choppy, begin and end updates took care of the animation itself.  Figured it was worth a try.